# Path directory in Tomcat using Restlet

Tags: tomcat, restlet, restlet-2.0

I have my restlet.Component deployed in Tomcat, in this, i read a configuration file of my app:

```
this.properties.load(new FileInputStream("config/conf.properties));
```

I have got a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

My webapp structure is:

```
/mi-webapp
  /config
     conf.properties
  /WEB-INF
    /classes
    /lib
    web.xml
```

How can i get the real path in restlet? i read about `ServletContext.getRealPath()` but it's a bad practice, how do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the config directory inside `WEB-INF/classes` and use this code instead:

```
    URL url = this.class.getClassLoader().getResource("config/conf.properties");
    try {
        this.properties.load(url.openStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't open/load properties file");
    }
```

This way you load the file from the classpath which is within the scope of your application anyway, and doesn't result in any security holes.